# Как объединить 3 класса с помощью метод GroupJoin и вывести среднее значение у 3 класса

Tags: c#, linq

Даны три класса:

```
 public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }        
    }

    public class ItemType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class Rate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
    }
```

На вход поступает некоторое количество строк с данными классов. Группы данных разделены пустой строкой. Для каждого товара надо вывести его идентификатор, имя, тип, стоимость и среднюю оценку (округлить до 1 цифры после запятой). Сортировать по цене по возрастанию, и по оценке по убыванию.

Входные данные:

```
1, R2D2, 2, 5500
2, T1000, 3, 15000
3, BMO, 1, 5500
4, C3-PO, 3, 12500
5, WALL-E, 2, 6500

1, Телефон
2, Пылесос
3, Приставка

1, 5, 1
2, 4, 2
3, 5, 3
4, 4, 4
5, 4, 5
6, 5, 2
7, 4, 1
8, 5, 5
9, 4, 3
10, 5, 4
11, 4.3, 4
12, 5, 3
13, 4.5, 2
14, 4, 1
15, 4, 5
```

Выходные данные:

```
3, BMO, Телефон, 5500, 4.7
1, R2D2, Пылесос, 5500, 4.3
5, WALL-E, Пылесос, 6500, 4.3
4, C3-PO, Приставка, 12500, 4.4
2, T1000, Приставка, 15000, 4.5
```

Я создал 3 списка для каждого класса, и планировал объединить эти списки с помощью метод GroupJoin по `ItemTypeId` но столкнулся с проблемами:

1. Не понимаю как в классе Rate вывести среднюю оценку для каждого типа товара
2. Как при объединение 3 классов, взять из класса `ItemType` свойство Name

Код который я написал:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Cost { get; set; }
    public Item(int id, string name, int itemTypeId, int cost)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        ItemTypeId = itemTypeId;
        Cost = cost;
    }
}

public class ItemType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ItemType(int id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class Rate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Rate(int id, double value, int itemid)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = value;
        ItemId = itemid;

    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Первый набор данных класс ITEM 
        List<Item> list1 = new List<Item>();

        while (true)
        {
            var p = Console.ReadLine();
            if (p == "" || p == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var p1 = p.Split(", ");
                list1.Add(new Item(int.Parse(p1[0]), p1[1], int.Parse(p1[2]), int.Parse(p1[3])));
            }
        }
        // Второй набор данных класс ItemType 
        List<ItemType> list2 = new List<ItemType>();
        while (true)
        {
            var p = Console.ReadLine();
            if (p == "" || p == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var p1 = p.Split(", ");
                list2.Add(new ItemType(int.Parse(p1[0]), p1[1]));
            }
        }
        // Третий набор данных класс Rate
        List<Rate> list3 = new List<Rate>();
        while (true)
        {
            var p = Console.ReadLine();
            if (p == "" || p == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                var p1 = p.Split(", ");
                list3.Add(new Rate(int.Parse(p1[0]), double.Parse(p1[1]), int.Parse(p1[2])));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Вам сначала надо подготовить список предметов, объединив их с типом, для этого достаточно простого `Join`, получите что-то на подобии этого: `var items = list1.Join(list2, item => item.ItemTypeId, type => type.Id, (item, type) => new {  item.Id, item.Name, Type = type, item.Cost });`, имея уже это, по аналогии можно уже соединять последний список с тем, что получился ранее, заменяя `ItemId` на нужный результат.

Comment: А как проссумировать получившийся Value для каждого товара и вывести среднюю, просто если мы через join с 3 списком пойдем, то средняя не выведится, а получается такой результат

R2D2, 5
R2D2, 4
R2D2, 4
T1000, 4
T1000, 5
T1000, 4,5
BMO, 5
BMO, 4
BMO, 5
C3-PO, 4
C3-PO, 5
C3-PO, 4,3
WALL-E, 4
WALL-E, 5
WALL-E, 4
Каждому товара будет соотвествовать оценка, но проссумировать их и вывести среднюю я что-то не пойму как

Comment: В конце, когда все соедините, когда у вас будет на руках конкретный список, где не Id, а конкретные данные, делайте уже `Group`, ну или последний лист через `GroupJoin` (как вы и хотели), а затем сделайте `Select` с формированием нужного вам вида и подсчетом нужных данных.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось как-то так

```
public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
        public int Cost { get; set; }
        public Item(int id, string name, int itemTypeId, int cost)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            ItemTypeId = itemTypeId;
            Cost = cost;
        }
    }
    
    public class ItemType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ItemType(int id, string name)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
        }
    }
    
    public class Rate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public Rate(int id, double value, int itemid)
        {
            Id = id;
            Value = value;
            ItemId = itemid;
    
        }
        public Rate(double value, int itemid)
        {
            Value = value;
            ItemId = itemid;
    
        }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // Первый набор данных класс ITEM 
            List<Item> list1 = new List<Item>();
    
            while (true)
            {
                var p = Console.ReadLine();
                if (p == "" || p == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    var p1 = p.Split(", ");
                    list1.Add(new Item(int.Parse(p1[0]), p1[1], int.Parse(p1[2]), int.Parse(p1[3])));
                }
            }
            // Второй набор данных класс ItemType 
            List<ItemType> list2 = new List<ItemType>();
            while (true)
            {
                var p = Console.ReadLine();
                if (p == "" || p == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    var p1 = p.Split(", ");
                    list2.Add(new ItemType(int.Parse(p1[0]), p1[1]));
                }
            }
            // Третий набор данных класс Rate
            List<Rate> list3 = new List<Rate>();
            while (true)
            {
                var p = Console.ReadLine();
                if (p == "" || p == null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    var p1 = p.Split(", ");
                    list3.Add(new Rate(int.Parse(p1[0]), double.Parse(p1[1]), int.Parse(p1[2])));
                }
            }
            var JoinLists12 = list1.Join(list2, x => x.ItemTypeId, y => y.Id, (x, y) =>
            new { Name = x.Name, NameList2 = y.Name, Id = x.Id, Cost = x.Cost, TypeId = x.ItemTypeId });
    
            var JoinList123 = list3.GroupBy(x => x.ItemId);
            var list123 = new List<Rate>();
            foreach(var p in JoinList123) 
            {
                double Value = 0;
                int counter = 0;
                foreach(var k in p) 
                {
                    Value += k.Value;
                    counter++;
                }
                list123.Add(new Rate(Value/counter, p.Key));
            }
            var JoiJoin = JoinLists12.Join(list123, x => x.Id, y => y.ItemId, (x, y)
                => new { itemid = x.Id, Name = x.Name, NameList2 = x.NameList2, Cost = x.Cost, Value = y.Value }).OrderBy(x => x.Cost).ThenByDescending( x => x.Value);
            foreach(var p in JoiJoin) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{p.itemid}, {p.Name}, {p.NameList2}, {p.Cost}, {p.Value:0.0}");
            }
    
        }
    }
```